# Running multiple nunit test classes in VS Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, nunit

In `Visual Studio` I have a Test Case folder with many test classes inside, for example `TestSet1.cs`, `TestSet2.cs` etc...
Within each class is my `nunit` framework (setup, tests, teardown methods).  In Test Explorer I see these classes in hierarchy order, with the tests within them, and can execute all of them.

In `VS Code` however, it is only recognizing 1 test file (even though I have 2). When I run `dotnet test testProject.csproj`  I get `A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern`

I also added the extension `.NET Core Test Explorer` but even that is only recognizing 1 test file.

Any ideas why this works fine in Visual Studio but not VS Code? The test class files are at the same directory level.

Answer (score 0):

That was happening to me. What I did was copy the good file and paste it into the new one. I realized that this file worked so I undid the changes and I noticed that I missed the attribute `[Test]` in the method.

Your post helped me realize what was going on and that is why I did the copy thing.

I hope this helps you.

Thank you